# Class visibilities and instantiation in MVP

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am hoping to use the MVP pattern in Android that I roughly came up with the following packages and classes:

Here are 3 packages:

```
com.myview

mainActivity  //public

com.ipresenter

IPresenter  //public

com.PresenterImpl

Presenter  //protected
```

Presenter `implements` IPresenter.

What I intend to do is to make `Presenter` protected and can be instantiated only in `mainActivity`. Other words, I would like to limit its visibility and creation of this class can only be made possible through `mainActivity` class.

Since its constructor is implicitly declared as protected, I cannot instantiate `Presenter` within class `mainActivity`.

How could I do this without having to make `Presenter` `public`? How can I limit the visibility of a (or some) class within a package and allow its creation only through another class that lies within another package?

I thought about the `classLoader` Iterator method, but is this an overkill or it is not necessary because there are other ways / patterns?

Many books seem to suggest to limit the visibility of classes as much as we can, so I am taking this opportunity to learn and utilize good practice.

*Addendum:*

In addition to the aforementioned, my ultimate goal is to be able to declare the presenter within the `mainActivity` using the interface type. So, if in the future I had more than one presenters, they would all still be of the interface type `IPresenter`.

Comment: If you only want it to be used in mainActivity and nowhere else, you could make it a private static nested class of mainActivity.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for response. Can you show me how to do this? In addition, why would it be different if I wanted to use it not just in `mainActivity`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html -- However, MVP classes should be able to "play" together, so you really shouldn't have Presenter be protected. This defeats the purpose of being able to separate concerns if you don't allow the separate pieces to "see" eachother.